# dc bubble chart X axis range

Tags: d3.js, dc.js

Even if I set

```
 bChart.x(d3.scale.linear().domain([0, 1000]))
```

It shows x-axis ticks from -200 or so. I want to remove the negative marks. Please suggest.

Comment: You're setting the domain for the y axis in your code sample. Is that a typo?

Comment: Yea thats a typo .. thanks for pointing out.And I figured out the answer as well. Going to post it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just figured out the problem. It was because of the X-axis padding that I was applying unknowingly to the bChart.

I reset the padding to zero and axis domain becomes as expected.

```
 bChart.xAxisPadding(0)
```